# Multiplayer game server sync

Tags: javascript, multiplayer, client-server, interpolation, movement-prediction

I am building a 2d multiplayer game with no physics and my own authoritative server. Already have all players getting synced each with other but their movement isn't so smooth yet.

Here is the mechanics:
- player clicks on the screen to move towards the mouse pointer. Client sends action + angle to server
- server calculate new position based on a certain speed and sends it back
- player then moves through interpolation

After reading a lot of articles and play around with few samples code, I still have my doubts about how to get the clock right on both sides.

Would the approach below be suitable for my type of game?
- Run the server at 1000/10
- Run the Client network loop at 1000/60 and the game loop at 1000/60

Also do I need a game loop running in the server at 1000/60?

Answer (score 3):

The clock speed matters less, as long as you make sure the server and the client game steps are kept in sync. [This article](https://medium.com/javascript-multiplayer-gamedev/chronicles-of-the-development-of-a-multiplayer-game-part-2-loops-and-leaks-10b453e843e0#.gok2ouw57) by Gary Weiss discusses this issue. Essentially either the game loop on the client or the server be late/early and you need to take care of these discrepancies.

Here's a proposed piece of code he wrote to implement these syncs (in JS):

```
// the game loop runs with an adjusting setTimeout call
let nextExecTime = null;
let gameLoop = () => {
    let stepStartTime = (new Date()).getTime();
    this.step();

    // delay/hurry the execution of next step if requested.
    // this could happen because of client-server step drift.
    nextExecTime = stepStartTime + this.options.stepPeriod;
    if (this.delayNextStep) {
        nextExecTime += STEP_DELAY_MSEC;
        this.delayNextStep = false;
    } else if (this.hurryNextStep) {
        nextExecTime -= STEP_DELAY_MSEC;
        this.hurryNextStep = false;
    }

    setTimeout(gameLoop, nextExecTime - (new Date()).getTime());
};

// in same cases, setTimeout is ignored by the browser,
// this is known to happen during the first 100ms of a touch event
// on android chrome.  Double-check the game loop using requestAnimationFrame
let gameLoopChecker = () => {
    let currentTime = (new Date()).getTime();
    if (currentTime > nextExecTime) {
        this.step();
        nextExecTime = currentTime + this.options.stepPeriod;
    }
    window.requestAnimationFrame(gameLoopChecker);
};
```

Note for the sake of transparency: me and Gary are co-developers of an open-source library for multiplayer games in Javascript: [Lance](http://lance.gg/)